# getting number of records from 2 tables - one to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, join, view

I have problem with search query that i have to built on the fly to return records from the database.

I have 2 tables: `adds and`adds_filters`. For the sake of simplicity, i make the table adds shorter than it is, removing some of the (irrelevant) fields
My table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `adds` (
`addid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`memberid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`isnew` int(11) NOT NULL,
`catid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`manufacturerid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`modelid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`colorid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`geographicareaid` int(45) NOT NULL,
`addtypeid` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`addcreatedon` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`addvalidfrom` date NOT NULL,
`addvaliduntil` date NOT NULL,
`addcreatedfromip` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`yearofmanufacturing` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`monthofmanufacturing` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`hoursused` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`cc2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`horsepowers` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`metalic` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`isdamaged` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`price` float DEFAULT NULL,
`hasvat` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
`canbenegotiated` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`addtitle` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`addtext` text NOT NULL,
`youtubevideo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`visible` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`ff1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`ff2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`ff3` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`ff4` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`addid`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=43 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `adds_filters` (
`addfilterid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`addid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`filterid` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`addfilterid`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=45 ;
```

[**Here is the fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44847d/1)

Problem is that user can add more than one filter for each adds, that is if the 
vehicle has AC,GPS, removable cabin and so on...This data is stored in the `adds_filters`. So, one add can have many filters.

How the query should look like when user choose that `catid` is 1, `manufacturerid` is 1  and then users check filters with ids 
67 and 158 for example?

I would prefer view over the query, but i have no idea how can i build such view. Reason from preferring the view is that in such a case, i will be able to use select * instead of complicated queries...

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: For the sake of clarity, please, provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE adds;` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE adds_filters;`. You can [post it here](http://pastebin.com/) if its too big

Comment: Alexander, i just edit my post, please take a look

Comment: [Here is the fiddle for you](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a60941) Add some inserts, so we could have sample data, and provide the desired output (and also the queries you already tried)

Comment: i add the data in the tables...please check it.

Comment: You need to provide the link. The fiddle is changing every time you modify it, so your fiddle is already has another url :)

Comment: i didn't know that.... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44847d/1

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47835/discussion-between-alexander-and-user2417624)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this table structure, you gonna need subqueries for each checked `filterid`, if you want `filterid`s to be displayed.
Without displaying, you can just use `DISTINCT` and `IN`.

[Here is the query without displaying `filterid`s](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44847d/30)

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
          FROM adds a
               JOIN adds_filters f
                    ON a.`addid` = f.`addid`
         WHERE      a.`catid` = 1
               AND  a.`manufacturerid` = 1
               AND  f.`filterid` IN (67, 158);
```

[Here is the query, that displays two different `filterid`s](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44847d/29):

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.filterid as filterid2
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT a.*,
       f.`filterid`
          FROM adds a
               JOIN adds_filters f
                    ON a.`addid` = f.`addid`
         WHERE      a.`catid` = 1
               AND  a.`manufacturerid` = 1
               AND  f.`filterid` = 67
) t1

JOIN 

(
SELECT DISTINCT a.`addid`,
       f.`filterid`
          FROM adds a
               JOIN adds_filters f
                    ON a.`addid` = f.`addid`
         WHERE      a.`catid` = 1
               AND  a.`manufacturerid` = 1
               AND  f.`filterid` = 158

  ) t2
ON t1.addid = t2.addid;
```

Comment: That is not the problem. My problem is the join that have to be done between 2 tables. Please re-read my question, especially the part bellow of the code