# modifying this complicated mySql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, adds, and adds_filters

Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `adds` (
    `addid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `memberid` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `isnew` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `catid` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `manufacturerid` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `modelid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `colorid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `geographicareaid` int(45) NOT NULL,
    `addtypeid` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `addcreatedon` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `addvalidfrom` date NOT NULL,
    `addvaliduntil` date NOT NULL,
    `addcreatedfromip` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `yearofmanufacturing` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `monthofmanufacturing` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `hoursused` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `cc2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `horsepowers` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `metalic` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
    `isdamaged` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
    `price` float DEFAULT NULL,
    `hasvat` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
    `canbenegotiated` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
    `addtitle` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `addtext` text NOT NULL,
    `youtubevideo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `visible` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
    `ff1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `ff2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `ff3` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `ff4` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`addid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=43 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `adds_filters` (
    `addfilterid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `addid` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `filterid` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`addfilterid`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=45 ;
```

I have the following sql query that works like a charm, but I need to modify it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.addid
              , a.memberid
              , a.isnew
              , a.catid
              , a.manufacturerid
              , a.modelid
              , a.colorid
              , a.geographicareaid
              , a.addtypeid
              , a.addcreatedon
              , a.addvalidfrom
              , a.addvaliduntil
              , a.addcreatedfromip
              , a.yearofmanufacturing
              , a.monthofmanufacturing
              , a.hoursused
              , a.cc2
              , a.horsepowers
              , a.metalic
              , a.isdamaged
              , a.price
              , a.hasvat
              , a.canbenegotiated
              , a.addtitle
              , a.addtext
              , a.youtubevideo
              , a.visible
              , a.ff1
              , a.ff2
              , a.ff3
              , a.ff4
           FROM adds a
           JOIN adds_filters f
             ON f.addid = a.addid 
          WHERE a.catid = 1
            AND a.manufacturerid = 1
            AND f.filterid IN (67,158)
```

My problem here is the following: if I add one more filter, (example 162) query should returns no results, since there is no add that has all 3 filters. Current query returns 3 rows, which all have the 67 and 158. Anyone can tell me how can I get the desired result?

Regards, John

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting number of records from 2 tables - one to many relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21876313/getting-number-of-records-from-2-tables-one-to-many-relationship)

Comment: But I already answered on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21876313/getting-number-of-records-from-2-tables-one-to-many-relationship/21876738#21876738) question. You said the answer was complete. What is the problem now?

Comment: i did. and my boss then suddenly change his mind....

Comment: i hoped to see you here to be honest....I will be back in 2 min.

Comment: well, you better be more clear than on what exactly you need to modify, because right now I cannot follow

Comment: GROUP BY addid HAVING COUNT(*) = n [WHERE n is the number of arguments in IN()]

Comment: Why are they called 'adds'. Surely 'adds' is short for '*ad*vertisements'!

Comment: @Strawberry I think 'ads' short for advertisement

Comment: Alexander: this query now return 3 rows. they all have filters 67 and 158. none of them have the filter 162. if i add that filter in the query, I should get 0 results. current query returns 3 rows even if i add the filter that those 3 adds doesn't have it.

Comment: it is actually short for classified adds

Comment: "adds" again. They're "classified ads" or "advertisements" - what you guys across the pond used to call "commercials" - before the internet came along. :-)

Comment: @user2417624 use the **second** query from my previous answer

Comment: let me check that...i will post the result here...

Comment: this works, just short question to be sure that i understand it right:   that means that i should add SELECT DISTINCT a.`addid`,
       f.`filterid`
          FROM adds a
               JOIN adds_filters f
                    ON a.`addid` = f.`addid`
         WHERE      a.`catid` = 1
               AND  a.`manufacturerid` = 1
               AND  f.`filterid` = 158

  ) t3 and t4....and t++ for each checked filter, correct?

Comment: @user2417624 absolutely!

Comment: @Strawberry 'Adds' is usually short for 'additional', I think you might be right about the user using  a faulty abbreviation. Not sure which side of the pond you talking about, I thought commercial was used on both sides?

Comment: Alexander, thanks. Please make this an answer, so i can accept it please....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is **SQLfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44847d/31)
You should understand, that you gonna need to dynamicaly add the subqueries to each checked `filterid`.

Here is the query (you also can play with `filterid`s in the main `SELECT`:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.filterid as filterid2
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT a.*,
       f.`filterid`
          FROM adds a
               JOIN adds_filters f
                    ON a.`addid` = f.`addid`
         WHERE      a.`catid` = 1
               AND  a.`manufacturerid` = 1
               AND  f.`filterid` = 67
) t1

JOIN 

(
SELECT DISTINCT a.`addid`,
       f.`filterid`
          FROM adds a
               JOIN adds_filters f
                    ON a.`addid` = f.`addid`
         WHERE      a.`catid` = 1
               AND  a.`manufacturerid` = 1
               AND  f.`filterid` = 158

  ) t2
ON t1.addid = t2.addid

JOIN 

(
SELECT DISTINCT a.`addid`,
       f.`filterid`
          FROM adds a
               JOIN adds_filters f
                    ON a.`addid` = f.`addid`
         WHERE      a.`catid` = 1
               AND  a.`manufacturerid` = 1
               AND  f.`filterid` = 162

  ) t3

ON t1.addid = t3.addid;
```

Comment: just a short question...how the query will look like if user check only one checkbox??

Comment: Just remover everything after the first `JOIN` (include this first `JOIN` word)

Comment: i  tried that but i get: #1054 - Unknown column 't2.filterid' in 'field list'

Comment: I don't understand what advantage this solution offers over a simple `GROUP BY... HAVING` clause !?!?!

Comment: @Strawberry hard to say, without your code. Could you use my prepared fiddle to show your statement?

Comment: Every field needs to be in the output @Strawberry

Comment: So include every field. What's the problem? :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply change your join to the adds_filters component

```
   FROM adds a
      JOIN ( select addid
                from adds_filters
               where filterid in ( 67, 158, 162 )
               group by addid
               having count(*) = 3 ) f
             ON f.addid = a.addid 
   WHERE a.catid = 1
     AND a.manufacturerid = 1
```

By changing to a prequery of only those AddIDs that have all 3 components (via group by and having), it will only return those valid AddIDs

Comment: please bear in mind that i have no idea how many checkboxes user may check. there are plenty of them.

Comment: @user2417624, then if you are building the query, just change the IN () list, and update the HAVING count value.  Also, if you want ALL filters selected as the query, the original one you have is incorrect as it will return ANY add that has 1, the other OR both... which I think is not what you want anyhow.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM adds a JOIN ( select addid from adds_filters ' at line 1...gulp...

Comment: @user2417624, I didn't mean just "FROM", but your entire select statement of Select ... all the fields....  You just needed to change the query starting at the "FROM" clause.  What I supplied is not a full query in itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to go with the suggestion by DRapp, but if there are issues knowing how many filters there are in advance when building the SQL then another possibility would me one inner join per filter.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.addid
              , a.memberid
              , a.isnew
              , a.catid
              , a.manufacturerid
              , a.modelid
              , a.colorid
              , a.geographicareaid
              , a.addtypeid
              , a.addcreatedon
              , a.addvalidfrom
              , a.addvaliduntil
              , a.addcreatedfromip
              , a.yearofmanufacturing
              , a.monthofmanufacturing
              , a.hoursused
              , a.cc2
              , a.horsepowers
              , a.metalic
              , a.isdamaged
              , a.price
              , a.hasvat
              , a.canbenegotiated
              , a.addtitle
              , a.addtext
              , a.youtubevideo
              , a.visible
              , a.ff1
              , a.ff2
              , a.ff3
              , a.ff4
           FROM adds a
           INNER JOIN adds_filters f1
             ON f1.addid = a.addid AND f1.filterid = 67
           INNER JOIN adds_filters f2
             ON f2.addid = a.addid AND f2.filterid = 158
           INNER JOIN adds_filters f3
             ON f3.addid = a.addid AND f3.filterid = 162
          WHERE a.catid = 1
            AND a.manufacturerid = 1
```